# Save an Image/Bitmap from hidden panels

Tags: c#, bitmap, save, panel, tabcontrol

I have a TabControl with four tabs, and every Tab contains a panel. 
I want save all panels with one click, but i can only save the panel in the front.

Do anyone know another way ?

```
Bitmap eins = new Bitmap(p1.Width, p1.Height);
eins.Save(".string."+1+".jpg",System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see where you are filling anything into the `Bitmap`.

This should work for all your  `Panels`, no matter which `TabPage` they are on:

```
foreach (Panel px in new Panel[] { p1, p2, p3, p4 } )
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pX.ClientSize.Width, pX.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        pX.DrawToBitmap(bmp, pX.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(somefolder + pX.Name + ".jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

In fact it will even work if the `Panels` are **actually** **invisible** and not just in one of the hidden `TabPages` !

Of course you must make sure that the `Panels` have unique and filename compliant `Names`..

**Update**: Now that I know that you have `Controls` **inside** the `Panel` and not just graphics you draw and maybe a `BackgroundImage`, I can understand the problems you had..

Unfortunately `TabPages` have a nasty way of hiding embedded controls.

So I wrote a little helper routine that doesn't cause more than a blink of the main form going inactive and back..:

```
void SaveHiddencontrol(Control ctl, string fileName)
{
    Control originalParent = ctl.Parent;

    Form fff = new Form();
    fff.Opacity = 0;
    ctl.Parent = fff;
    fff.Show();
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".png")) fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(fileName, fmt);
    }
    ctl.Parent = originalParent;
    fff.Close();
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Note how the `Form` itself is completely **transparent** and yet lets the `Panel` do its `DrawToBitmap` just fine, including an image, an ellipse and two controls and even **independent** of the `Form.Size` ..!

**Update2** And here is a function that dosn't blink at all, at least if the panel is indeed not visible:

```
void SaveHiddencontrol(Control ctl, string fileName)
{
    Control originalParent = ctl.Parent;
    int oldLeft = ctl.Left;
    ctl.Left = 22222;  // way outside
    ctl.Parent = this;
    System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg;
    if (fileName.ToLower().EndsWith(".png")) fmt = System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png;
    using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(ctl.ClientSize.Width, ctl.ClientSize.Height))
    {
        ctl.DrawToBitmap(bmp, ctl.ClientRectangle);
        bmp.Save(fileName, fmt);
    }
    ctl.Parent = originalParent;
    ctl.Left = oldLeft;
}
```

This simply moves the `Panel` onto the main `Form` but `way to the right`, so that it won't show. Then saves and it moves it back. Of course you should check if the `Panel` is indeed on a hidden `TabPage` or else it will blink; in that case the original routine will do..

Comment: Thank you, i will try this later.  I used the control.drawtoBitmap() function too.

Comment: it works great! Thanks. 
Another question : Is it possible to get all panels without clicking every tab ? I have to click every tab, without clicking the panel is black.

Comment: That would be strange; I can save the panels from hidden pages without a problem, just as I wrote in the answer. Can you explain what the panel contains?

Comment: The panels contain only labels and a chart

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I have updated the answer by a routine that solves the problem.. If you want to save several panels you may want to change it to accept a `List<Control>`..

Comment: Hey I'm sorry i was busy the last days. Your solution works great ! Thank you so much. Really Cool